# Alpaca Addresses

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, alpacajs

Hello!

I'm new to Alpaca. I understand it's not in (very) active development, but I'm using it for its ease-of-use when it comes to repeating fields and grouping standard fields such as US addresses. I've mastered setting the default values of fields of type "address." However, the address field comes with support for Google Maps built-in, and I don't see in the documentation a way to make it impossible to use Google Maps. My question is, is there a way to disable it? If not, can you please show me the proper way to invoke Google Maps with my own API key and mention where it should be placed in reference to the Alpaca <script> tags and the $.("...").alpaca() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I set "addressValidation" to false, the Google Map goes away. It currently needs to be "addressValidation" and not "validateAddress" as the document suggest.